# Unable to fetch mongodb collection in nodejs application using mongoose, inserted through aws lambda function using MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I inserted document using MongoClient() and fetching using Mongoose but unfortunately it fetch an empty array.
Basically I inserted inside Lambda and fetching inside node app

```
       let getCustomRegs = await db.find("customRegulation", {});
       console.log("getCustomRegs: ", getCustomRegs); //return empty array
```

Comment: what do you want to fetch from db?

Comment: @mehta-rohan i want all objects from that collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you inserted using MongoDb it inserted docs without schema and then when you fetch using mongoose.schema you should add .toArray() with your find request to convert response to an array.
You should do like this

```
 mongoose.connection.db.collection("customRegulation", async function(
  err,
  collection
) {
  let data = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  console.log(data);
});
```